# Can ZFC be interpreted in the following type-set theory?

Tags: set-theory, alternative-set-theories

Language: first order logic with equality and its axiom and additionally the extra-logical primitives: $ ``\tau, < , \in"$, the first is a total unary function denoting *is the type of*, the rest are binary relations denoting, *is lower than* and *set membership* respectively.

Axioms:

**Extensionality:** $\forall z (z \in x \Leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$

*Define:* $t \text{ is a type} \equiv_{df} \exists x: t=\tau(x)$

**Well ordering:**  $< \text {is a  well-order on types } $

**Idempotence:** $\tau(\tau(x))=\tau(x)$

**Infinity:** $  \exists  t: \lim^< t$

**Atomicity:** $\forall \text{type } t: \forall y \, (y \in t \iff y=t)$

**Typed Comprehension:** $\forall   t \, \exists x \, \forall y \, (y \in x \iff  \tau(y) < t \land \phi)$

**Typing:** $ \neg (x \text { is a type}) \to \tau(x)= \min t: \forall y \in x ( t > \tau(y))$

**Inaccessibility:** if $f$ is a definable function, then:

$ \forall x : \neg \, \forall \text{type } t \, \exists y \, \in x \, (t \leq f(y))$

Where: $a \leq b \equiv_{df} a < b \lor a=b$.

*Note:* the expression $``< \text{ is a well order on types}"$ is the following axioms:

$\begin{align} \forall x \forall y \, (& x < y \to x,y \text { are types }  \\& x \not < x \\ &  x < y < z \to x < z \\ &   x,y \text { are types} \land x \neq y \iff x < y \lor y < x  )\end{align}\\ \exists \, \text{type } x (\phi(x)) \to \exists \, \text {type } x: \phi(x) \land \neg \exists y \, (\phi(y) \land y < x) $

the expression $``\lim^< t"$ is:

$\exists a (a < t) \land \forall a < t \exists b < t \, (a < b)$

the expressions $``\forall \text{type } x ..; \exists \text { type } x .."$ stands for $ \forall x \, (x \text{ is a type } \to ..)$ and $\exists x \, (x \text{ is a type } \land .. )$ respectively.

> Now is ZFC interpretable in this theory?

Comment: Everything seems to allow for an interpretation of "types" as ordinals -- except for Atomicity, which I would expect to say $(y\in t \iff y < t)$  [$<$ not $=$].

Comment: @BrianO, if I follow you correctly then you would by then interpret $\tau$ as the rank function on sets, that is $\tau(x)=\alpha$ is interpreted as $rank(x)=\alpha$. My philosophical belief is that Types are not sets, that's why I prefer to axiomatize them as extensional Ur-elements

Comment: That was the other interpretation it seems the axioms offer. Is the logic one-sorted or two-sorted? If you want types to not be sets, I'd think 2-sorted. If not, then the variable $y$ in Atomicity ranges over both sets and types, and it follows that $t\in t$ for every type $t$.

Comment: @BrianO, it's mono-sorted. Yes, we do have $t \in t$ for every type $t$ still that doesn't make it a set, even though it is extensional, and even though it is an "element" of itself; the reason is because its identity is dependent only on  a relationship with itself, so to me this is not a set. Of course we can use two sorts, but I just want to make matters easiers this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is to the positive. I was just wondering if Replacement can follow from inaccessibility of types, which happens to be the case! A point that I didn't see clearly at the begining. This shows that naive conception about types with sets constructed thereof is a strong notion! Since it can easily interpret set theory.

The proof is actually almost straighforward.

**Lemma:** there is no maximal type:

$\not \exists t^{max}: \forall \text{type } t \, (t < t^{max})$

Proof: suppose there is a maximal type $t^{max}$. Define the fixed function $f(y)=t^{max}$. Now take any set $x$ such that $y \in x$ and we'll have every type $t \leq f(y)$; contradicting Inaccessibility.

**The proof of Replacement:**  for any definable function $f$ (not using symbol $B$) for any set $A$, there exists a set $B$ that is a set image of $A$ under $f$.

Proof: Define the function $i$ from $A$ as $i(x)=\tau(f(x))$ for each $x \in A$, so $i$ is the restriction of the composition $\tau \circ f$ to $A$. Now assume that for every type $t$ there exists some $i(x)$ for an $x \in A$ such that $t \leq i(x)$; by then we'd violate Inaccessibility. So there must exist a type $t$ that is strictly higher than the type of every $f(x)$ when $x \in A$, use this type in Typed Comprehension, and construct the set image of $A$ under $f$.

**The proofs of Power and Set Union** are straighforward also, since simply we take a type  $t > \tau(x)$ and simply we can construct $P(x)$ and $\bigcup(x)$ by substituting this type in Typed comprehension with the relevant formulas.

**The proof of Infinity** is easy also, take $t$ in Typed comprehension to be the first limit type, and we can easily construct the set of *all* naturals. We can easily prove that no natural can have an infinite type, since otherwhise the types of all naturals with infinite types would constitute a descending type chain! Thus violating the Well Ordering schema.

So all axioms of $\sf ZF \text{ - Reg.} $ are proved in this theory, so clearly this theory would interpret $\sf ZFC$.