# Reference request: is axiom of choice motivated along type-set lines?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, axioms, type-theory, alternative-set-theories

Language: bi-sorted first order logic with equality and its axiom and additionally the extra-logical primitives: $ ``\tau, < , \in"$, the first is a total unary function on sets denoting *is the type of*, the rest are binary relations denoting, *is lower than* and *set membership* respectively. Sorts are: the first sort in Greek for *types*, the second sort in ordinary English  for *sets*. Syntatic restrictions include: $\tau$ only taking set symbols as arguments but their values are type symbols, $<$ only occur between type symbols, $\in$ only occur between set symbols.

Axioms:

[A]: *Type axioms*

**Well ordering:**  $< \text {is a strict  well-order on types; that is: } $

$\begin{align} \forall \alpha \forall \beta \, (& \alpha \not < \alpha \\ &  \alpha < \beta < \gamma \to \alpha < \gamma \\ &   \alpha \neq \beta \to \alpha < \beta \lor \beta < \alpha  )\end{align}\\ \exists \alpha (\phi(\alpha)) \to \exists \alpha: \phi(\alpha) \land \neg \exists \beta \, (\phi(\beta) \land \beta < \alpha) $

**Infinity:** $  \exists  \lambda : \exists \alpha (\alpha < \lambda) \land \forall \alpha < \lambda \exists \beta < \lambda \, (\alpha < \beta)$

[B]: *Type-Set axioms*

**Typed Comprehension:** if $\phi$ is a formula that does use the symbol $X$, then: $$\forall   \alpha \, \exists !X \, \forall y \, (y \in X \iff  \tau(y) < \alpha \land \phi)$$

**Typing:** $ \tau(X)= \min \alpha: \forall y \in X \, ( \alpha > \tau(y))$

**Inaccessibility:** if $f$ is a definable function, then: $$ \forall X : \neg \, \forall \alpha \, \exists y \, \in X \, (\alpha \leq f(y))$$

Where: $\alpha \leq \beta \iff \alpha < \beta \lor \alpha= \beta$.

Now I think that this theory is a conservative extension over ZF [see [here]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114858/can-zfc-be-interpreted-in-the-following-type-set-theory?answertab=active#tab-top), and over ZFC  should Choice be added to it. Moreover, this theory is a naive capture of conceptions about types and sets and portrays a naive enmeshment between them, that it can by itself be considered as motivating $\sf ZF$ set theory. However, what really irks me is that I'm not seeing a simple motivation for Axiom of Choice along type-set lines?

From what I know is that this is not new with me, and the idea of grounding ZF in a kind of type-set theory is old. I want in particular to ask about if there are known simple formulations of axiom of choice in type-set theories, that depends on types in an essential manner?

Comment: "I'm not seeing a simple motivation for Axiom of Choice along type-set lines" What would you consider a simple motivation for AC in *any* context? Is there a simple motivation for AC in the usual ZF setting, and if so what is it?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, it means an intuitive motivation along that context. For example take the scheme of Inaccessibility above, it has a simple formulation in terms of types and set membership and it does have a intuitive grasp along the type-set line of thought. However, I find it difficult to present choice in terms of types. AC seems to be a purely set theoretic concept, I don't see a clear intuitive type-set simile. In the usual set theory setting it is indeed intuitive that you can select an element from each set in a family of pairwise disjoint sets, there is a simple intuition into that.